# SUM of column dependent condition

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I have a query and output as seen below. I essentially want the `threshold` column to say `"YES"` once the threshold on `x.cum` is met (-3). And any rows after that threshold is met should also say `"YES"`. Currently it is doing the condition for each row independently. But what I want is once the condition is `FIRST` met, it should stay like that..

e.g.

```
cum    threshold   
-2.0   NO
-2.25  NO
-3.5   YES
-2.9   YES
-1.2   YES
-4.2   YES
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with your data is that it contains duplicate datetimes, so it is not possible to identify that *...once the condition is FIRST met...*. Is there any other column from which you can get a definitive order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*, case when min(cum) over(partition by s_day order by s_datetime) < -3 then 'YES' else 'NO' end
from (
    -- your query here --
) t
```

Comment: Ah right ok, didn't think of using MIN with the partition like that. Thanks!